# What does r = *(--p) + 1; do?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I've been working through Programming with C++ by John Hubbard and came across this question:

> Determine the values of each of the indicated variables after the following code executes. Assume that integers occupy 4 bytes and that `m` is stored in memory starting at byte `0x3ffd00`.

```
int m = 44;
int* p = &m;
int n = (*p)++;
int* q = p - 1;
r = *(--p) + 1;
++*q;
```

We are asked to find the values of

```
m
n
&m
*p
r
*q
```

after the code executes.

So I understand that r is a reference to m, and n is assigned the dereferenced value of p, and p is then incremented. So at that point m=r=45 and n=44. I don't understand what

```
int* q = p - 1; 
r = *(--p) + 1; 
++*q;
```

will do though. Can someone help me out?

Comment: "Let's see how much we can get away with before causing undefined behavior"

Comment: This question is straight from the book. I copied the question exactly as stated and am merely trying to learn how pointers work.

Comment: @Cyber, Too late. `p - 1` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @yublu why don't you just do a small test program?

Comment: @Claptrap - a test program may produce an answer, but it won't detect undefined behaviour. `valgrind` may (or may not) pick it up.

Comment: @abligh true, but teach somebody to fish etc.

Comment: typo: maybe `(*p)++` is supposed to be `*(p++)`, or some other such mistake.

Comment: I have tried a small test program, and it returned -1 for m, *p, r, and *q, and 44 for n. Perhaps this was just a poorly constructed question.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, (*p)++ is what's stated in the book.

Comment: @yublu - Please give Mr. Hubbard a lifeline and say that this is a typo: `int* q = p - 1;`

Comment: I'm watching this question 22 mins after it is asked. It is at -4, no close votes. Even though the statements themselves are provoking, I find the question clear and concise. OP has attempted a solution with a reasonable argument. I think OP deserves an explanation for the downvotes besides deriding the litterature OP is studying.

Comment: @chris Is `int* q = p - 1;` really undefined behaviour? I would have thought it only becomes undefined once you try to dereference the pointer `q`. And @MarcGlisse is right: if it was `int n = *(p++);` then it would all make sense!

Comment: @Oguk, Yes, an additive operator that produces an out of bounds result (since it's pointing to a single variable, it's treated as an array of one element) is undefined. The standardese is too long for a comment, but I made a [paste](http://pastebin.com/fKe7nKZP).

Comment: @chris That's interesting, thank you! In most implementations, it would probably not cause any trouble, but it could lead problems in the future, as demonstrated [here](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/stack:sosp13.pdf). Now I am even more certain that the line `int n = (*p)++;` is a typo (if not by the OP, then in the book the OP has been reading). If it was `int n = *(p++);`, not only would everything make sense, it would also mean that all the pointers either point to "something" or one element past "something", which is well-defined according to the text you posted.

Answer (score 1):

1. `p` is not a reference to `m`; `p` is a pointer to `m`. A pointer and a reference are different.
2. `q` is being defined as the pointer to the integer immediately prior to `m`. That is at an undefined location on the stack. Are you sure this didn't say "p+1", because ...
3. ... the next line (`r = *(--p) + 1;`) decrements p, takes the value at the pointer, and adds one. This is undefined behaviour unless there's a typo above.
4. `++*q` again increments a value at an undefined place - undefined behaviour. The questioner may be relying (or tempting you to rely) on the fact that it decrements and increments the same value, but that still is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Decrementing and incrementing pointers are commonly used in arrays.

When you decrement/increment a pointer, it DOES NOT decrement/increment the value it points to. What it DOES is, increment/decrement the address pointed to by the size of its data type.

```
int m = 44;
int* p = &m;
int n = (*p)++;  //n=45
int* q = p - 1;   //q point to &m-(sizeof(int)) , value of address pointed to by q would be undefined and may even cause segfault once accessed
r = *(--p) + 1; //undefined, we don't know what is the value in address &m-1, then add 1 to its value. May even cause segfault.
++*q;  //increment value pointed to by q(which is undefined and may even cause segfault)
```

Comment: Is it really that `int* q = p - 1;` is undefined behaviour and can cause a segfault? I would have thought it only is if you try to dereference q.

Comment: Yes your right. But its value would be undefined or will result to segfault once you accessed it.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but chris has posted a quote from the standard that convinced me of the opposite. So it really seems to be "undefined behaviour", although it will most certainly not result in a segfault at that point (but, since it's undefined, even that could happen...).

Comment: The reason its "undefined behavior" we dont know exactly what might happen. It MAY or MAY NOT segfault. Segfault only happens when you access a memory address wherein the process is not permited to(maybe outside of its heap space). The sample may not have segfault because the address its accessing is within its heap/scope.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I just thought (quite naively, without looking at the standard) that changing the address a pointer points to could never cause any trouble, as long as you don't access that address (however crazy it may be) by dereferencing the pointer. In most implementations, this is probably true because the pointer is really just stored as a 4 or 8 byte plain number and there are no side effects when decrementing a pointer (it really just changes that 4 or 8 byte number). But according to the standard, even that pointer decrement could go wrong, if the implementation chooses so.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pointer decrement could go wrong, if the implementation chooses so'?

Comment: I just mean, decrementing the pointer as in `p-1` is already undefined behaviour according to the standard (in contrast to what I thought in my first comment), as pointed out by chris in the comments under the main question. So basically, we have no guarantee whatsoever and anything can happen at that line. *What* is actually going to happen and *how bad* it is, is purely implementation-defined.